# Classmethod doesnot return any value when called from another class

Tags: python, openai-api, class-method, function-call

I have shared a part of a discord bot, where when i ask a query [ Ex: Show me all quotes from database ] it calls the new openai function calling, my problem is that when i call the function `add_quotes()` in `query_sort` it calls a method in `Sql_Query` Class but the method `select_all_quotes()` doesn't return any value in `data =  dict_function[function_name]` same is the case with `insert_quotes_auto()` method

```
import openai
import savedfile
from function_list import function_list
from regex import regex as re
import mysql.connector

class Quote_Getter(Sql_Query):

    def __init__(self,query):
        super().__init__()
        self.query = query

    def query_ai(self):
        openai.api_key = savedfile.openai_key()
        completion = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
        model="gpt-3.5-turbo-0613",
        messages=[
        {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful 
        assistant."},
        {"role": "user", "content": f"{self.query}"},],
        functions=function_list())

        response = completion.choices[0].message
        return response

    def query_sort(self):
        response=self.query_ai()
        print(response) ###<--- Works Fine 
        try:
          regex_arguments = re.sub(r"\t|\n|\r|\ |", '', 
          response["function_call"]["arguments"])
          print(regex_arguments) , ### <----- Works Fine

          dict_function = {
              "select_all_quotes": self.select_all_quotes(),
         "add_quotes":self.add_quotes(regex_arguments["amount"]),
        }

          function_call = response["function_call"]
          function_name = function_call["name"]
          data = dict_function[function_name] ### <---- Problem Here [ MAJOR ]
          #data = self.add_quotes(regex_arguments["amount"])
          print(data). <--- No Printing
          return data <--- No Return

        except:
          return response["content"] <---- Works Fine

     def answer_back(self):
          data = self.query_sort()
          return str(data)

  def add_quotes(self,amount):
    data = self.query_ai(f"Get me {amount} motivational quotes")
    data_list = list(map(lambda x: x[1],data.split("\n")))
    print(data_list)
    return self.insert_quotes_auto(data_list)

class Sql_Query():

    def __init__(self):
        self.mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        password="\*\*\*\*\*",
        database="quote_db")

    def insert_quotes_auto(self,data):
        cursor = self.mydb.cursor()
        for quo in data:
            cursor.execute(f'INSERT INTO quotes (Quotes) VALUES 
("{quo}");')
            self.update_Used("No",cursor.lastrowid)
        self.mydb.commit()
        return f"{cursor.rowcount} records inserted."

    def select_all_quotes(self):
        cursor = self.mydb.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM quotes")
        myresult = cursor.fetchall()
        quote_list = "\n".join(list(map(lambda x: 
x[0],myresult)))
        print(quote_list) ###<-------Works Fine Prints value in 
Terminal
        return quote_list ###<--------- Doesnot Return the value
```

Here is the Discord code that calls `answer_back()` method in `Quote_Getter`

```
import discord
from quotegetter import Quote_Getter
from savedfile import discord_api as discord_key

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
   print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    data = Quote_Getter(message.content).answer_back()
    await message.channel.send(data)

client.run(discord_key())
```

Output From Terminal:

This is the respose from Openai

```
{                                
  "role": "assistant",
  "content": null,
  "function_call": {
    "name": "select_all_quotes",
    "arguments": "{}"
  }
}
```

this is regex omtimised output for arguments

```
{} ###<--- For select_all_quotes
{"amount": 5} ###<-----  For insert_quotes_auto if i ask for 5 quotes
```

This is the printed value in terminal for `select_all_quotes()` Works Fine Here

```
The only way to do great work is to love what you do.
Believe you can and you're halfway there.
Success is not final, failure is not fatal: It is the courage to continue that counts.
The only way to do great work is to love what you do.
Don't watch the clock; do what it does. Keep going.
You are never too old to set another goal or to dream a new dream.
The future belongs to those who believe in the beauty of their dreams.
The only person you should try to be better than is the person you were yesterday.
Obstacles are those frightful things you see when you take your eyes off your goal.
Success is not the key to happiness. Happiness is the key to success. If you love what you are doing, you will be successful.
The only limit to our realization of tomorrow will be our doubts of today.
Believe you can and you're halfway there.
```

Comment: This code defines two classes but they are never _called_.  There must be other code you have not shown us.

Comment: Also, what is the point of the last paragraph?

Comment: Get rid of that bare `except:` and you may have a chance at figuring out what's actually happening.

Comment: @JohnGordon The last para is the print(quote_list) in select_all_quotes() it gives output in the terminal but something happens when it is returned

Comment: Oh, I see.  Those are inspirational quotes.  I assumed "quote" meant something with the stock market.

Comment: @JohnGordon i have also updated the the discord code that's calls method in class

Comment: @AKX Except is for when there is no need to call a function , that part of the code is working fine

Comment: If, as you say, that `print(regex_arguments)` produces output, but `print(data)` does not, then the implication is that there was an error raised somewhere between the two, which is caught by the bare `except:`. Now you don't know what happened. Better to use exact exception types.

Comment: Try printing the exception in your `except:` block, so you'll know why the rest of the code is being skipped.